# CloudFoundry MySQL Java configuration

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a Spring MVC app that is running fine on local tomcat etc. Its a Spring 3.1 MVC/Hibernate app.

I am using (where possible) pure Java @Configuration for the app - and I am now trying to deploy the app to CloudFoundry (via STS), but I am struggling to get the MySql db configured (from memory, with xml config you dont need to do anything and Spring/CloudFoundry auto-injects the required user/password etc, but its been a while since I deployed anything to CF).

I have tried both of the following configurations:

```
@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
    //CloudFoundry config
    final CloudEnvironment cloudEnvironment = new CloudEnvironment();
        final List<MysqlServiceInfo> mysqlServices = cloudEnvironment.getServiceInfos(MysqlServiceInfo.class);
        final MysqlServiceInfo serviceInfo = mysqlServices.get(0);

    BasicDataSource bean = new BasicDataSource();
    bean.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    bean.setUrl(serviceInfo.getUrl());
    bean.setUsername(serviceInfo.getUserName());
    bean.setPassword(serviceInfo.getPassword());
    return bean;
}
```

The above failed on out of bounds on the `.get(0)` line of the mysqlServices. This was based on the answer suggested [here](http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20393268-Using-MySql-Hibernate-and-Configuration-in-Cloud-Foundry).

I also tried leaving the datasource as what it runs on as local to see if the properties just get injected, but no luck there either. (the below was tried with the values as per the Spring sample code [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/cloudfoundry-samples/blob/master/hello-spring-mysql/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml), and also using property placeholders from my db.connection props file)

```
@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
    BasicDataSource bean = new BasicDataSource();
    bean.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    bean.setUrl("");
    bean.setUsername("spring");
    bean.setPassword("spring");
    return bean;
}
```

---

Edit

I have also used the getServiceInfo(String, Class) method passing in the name of the MySql service that I have created and bound to the application, but that just NPEs similar to the getServiceInfos(..) approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was just a stupid mistake - when I deployed the app via STS I had selected Java Web app rather than the "Spring" type.  Not sure why that would make the CloudEnvironment properties not be available (I was under the impression that approach was the common method to inject the details in non-Spring apps) - but re-deploying it to the server as a Spring app resolved the probs!